# Plotly Choropleth

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly, choropleth

I am working with a Kaggle dataset "US Accidents" (which can be downloaded [here](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/sobhanmoosavi/us-accidents?resource=download)) that has 3 million records on traffic accident data. A quick exploration shows that California contains the most accidents. I thought a choropleth viz would be cool to implement however, the data on my Choropleth is inaccurate and was wondering where I am going wrong/how to fix it.
[image]
[image]

Here is my code...

```
states_by_accident = df.State.value_counts()

import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(data = go.Choropleth(
    locations = df.State.unique(),
    z = states_by_accident,
    locationmode = 'USA-states',
    colorscale = 'Blues'
))


fig.update_layout(
       geo_scope = 'usa'
   )
fig.show()
```

I have tried converting the colors to a log scale which helped spread out the coloring but it still displayed Ohio as having the most accidents which is inaccurate.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please paste the code from your notebook as text instead of images?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `df.State.unique()` doesn't have the states in the same order as the values in `states_by_accident`.

You can fix this by instead passing the argument `locations = states_by_accident.index` to `go.Chloropleth` so that the locations and values are consistent:

```
fig = go.Figure(data = go.Choropleth(
    locations = states_by_accident.index,
    z = states_by_accident,
    locationmode = 'USA-states',
    colorscale = 'Blues'
))
```

[image]